# Python scraping ASP site with embedded PDF viewer

Tags: python, html, asp.net, pdf

First post here, any help would be greatly appreciated :).
I'm trying to scrape from a website with an embedded pdf viewer. As far as I can tell, there is no way to directly download the PDF file.

The browser displays the pdf as multiple PNG image files, the problem is that the png files aren't directly accessible either. They are rendered from the original pdf and then displayed.

And the URL with the heading stripped out is in the codeblock.

The original URL to the pdf viewer (I'm using the second URL), and the link to render the pdf are included in the code.

My strategy here is to pull the viewstate and eventvalidation using urllib, then use wget to download all files from the site. This method does work without post data (page 1). I am getting the rest of the parameters from fiddler (sniffing tool)

But when I use post data to specify the page, I get 405 errors like these when trying to download the image files. However, it downloads the actual html page without a problem, just none of the png files that go along with it. Here is an example of the wget errors.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 405 Method Not Allowed
2014-03-27 17:09:38 ERROR 405: Method Not Allowed.

Since I can't access the image file link directly, I thought grabbing the entire page with wget would be my best bet. If anyone knows some better alternatives, please let me know :). The post data seems to work at least partially since the downloaded html file is set to the page I specified in parameters.

According to fiddler, the site automatically does a get request for the image file. I'm not quite sure how to emulate this however.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for your time!

```
imglink = 'http://201.150.36.178/consultaexpedientes/render/2132495e-863c-4b96-8135-ea7357ff41511.png'
origurl = 'http://201.150.36.178/consultaexpedientes/sistemas/boletines/wfBoletinVisor.aspx?tomo=1&numero=9760&fecha=14/03/2014%2012:40:00'

url = 'http://201.150.36.178/consultaexpedientes/usercontrol/Default.aspx?name=e%3a%5cBoletinesPdf%5c2014%5c3%5cBol_9760.pdf%7c0'
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
eventargs = soup.findAll(attrs={'type':'hidden'})
reValue = re.compile(r'value=\"(.*)\"', re.DOTALL)
viewstate = re.findall(reValue, str(eventargs[0]))[0]
validation = re.findall(reValue, str(eventargs[1]))[0]

params = urllib.urlencode({'__VIEWSTATE':viewstate,
                           '__EVENTVALIDATION':validation,
                           'PDFViewer1$PageNumberTextBox':6,
                           'PDFViewer1_BookmarkPanelScrollX':0,
                           'PDFViewer1_BookmarkPanelScrollY':0,
                           'PDFViewer1_ImagePanelScrollX' : 0,
                           'PDFViewer1_ImagePanelScrollY' : 0,
                           'PDFViewer1$HiddenPageNumber':6,
                           'PDFViewer1$HiddenAplicaMarcaAgua':0,
                           'PDFViewer1$HiddenBrowserWidth':1920,
                           'PDFViewer1$HiddenBrowserHeight':670,
                           'PDFViewer1$HiddenPageNav':''})


command = '/usr/bin/wget -E -H -k -K -p --post-data=\"%s'  % params + '\" ' + url
print command
os.system(command)
```